# How to update emberjs arrays so #each hears the changes?

Tags: arrays, ember.js, each

There are quite a few questions on how to get Each to update if you are inserting, or removing from an array that is a controller attribute. Simple, just use the MutableArrayMixin already builtin to Ember and do pushObject and removeObject.

However, if the array elements are objects, how does one update object attributes in a way so whatever htmlbar is in the #each knows it has to rerender itself?

For example, say I have some conditional CSS attribute that hides based on a filter within the #each.

I've tried converting the objects to Ember.Objects and using their set/get, but that doesn't solve the problem.

Here is some example code. I'd like to show you via jsbin, but can't get https://emberjs.jsbin.com/nobozazazu/edit?html,js,console,output to work

```
// within my component
export default Ember.Component.extend({
  items: function() {
    // some AJAX call to retrieve items from provided list of itemIds
    $.get('https://api.guildwars2.com/v2/items', {ids: itemIds.join(',')}).then(function(data) {
      for(var item = 0; item < data.length; item ++) {
        data[item] = Ember.Object.create(data[item])
        data[item].set('count',itemsToCount[data[item].id]);
        data[item].set('hiddenCSS', '');
        itemIdsWithData.push(data[item]);
      }
      this.set('itemData', itemIdsWithData);
    }
  }.property('itemIds'),

  filteredItems: function() {
    var selectedItem = this.get('selected');
    var itemData = this.get('itemData');

    for (var i = 0; i < itemData.length; i++) {
      if (selectedItem !== '' && selectedItem !== null && selectedItem.name === itemData[i].name) {
        itemData[i].hiddenCSS = '';
      }
      else {
        itemData[i].set('hiddenCSS', 'hidden');
      }
    }
    itemData.setObjects(itemData);

    // Verified both in Ember Inspector and with this log that itemData is changed
    console.log(itemData);
    // selected is provided from a top level route
  }.observes('selected')
})
```

From my component template
Even though ember inspector verifies item.hidden is changed, no class is reflected in html

```
{{#each itemData as |item|}}
  <div class="col-md-3 icon {{item.hidden}}">
    <img class="picture-icon" src= {{item.icon}} alt="Logo"> {{item.name}} x {{item.count}}
  </div>
{{/each}}
```

Note that I am working with versions

Ember Inspector
1.8.2
Ember
1.13.3
Ember Data
1.13.5
jQuery
1.11.3

TLDR: If you are working with Ember #each, you need to use MutableArray functions like pushObject and removeObject. If you want Ember to notice changes to the objects, you need to use Ember.Object objects in your array and do sets/gets with .get and .set.

Comment: Could you provide some code in your question?

Comment: I normally work with ember-cli. How do I get that onto jsbin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that your are not reading the correct value in your template.

Your JavaScript sets the `hiddenCSS` property:

```
itemData[i].set('hiddenCSS', 'hidden');
```

But your template reads the `hidden` property:

```
<div class="col-md-3 icon {{item.hidden}}">
```

Try this instead:

```
<div class="col-md-3 icon {{item.hiddenCSS}}">
```

Also, Ember.Objects will error if you try to set properties directly. Make sure to use set.

For instance, instead of:

```
itemData[i].hiddenCSS = ''
```

do

```
itemData[i].set('hiddenCSS', '')
```